# point tlmgr to a new release

Tags: texlive

I'M trying to update texlive from 2013 to 2014, using [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55459#55459), but after installing 2014, tlmgr doesn't know of the new version, and thus I can't update packages. How do I point tlmgr to the new release? My tlmgr is a symlink to

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The guide you refer to deals with the “vanilla” TeX Live, while you seem to have installed the Debian/TeX Live. If you installed the vanilla TL 2014, then you should adjust your `PATH` environment variable in order that `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/<arch>` is before `/usr/bin` (here `<arch>` stands for the architecture you have, check in `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/` to see what to substitute to it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have installed the “vanilla” TeX Live 2014 on a machine with TeX Live/Debian 2013. There's no problem in this and you don't need to remove TL/Debian unless you need space (you can fake an install with some `dpkg` trick with `equivs`).

The executable programs and scripts of the “vanilla” TeX Live sit in

```
/usr/local/texlive/<year>/bin/<arch>
```

(something there may be symbolic links, but always referring to something else with a relative path). All these programs are set up so that they know where they live and they search for files using relative paths (unless specifically told to use some absolute path).

Thus the trick is just to set your `PATH` environment variable so that

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/<arch>
```

(here `<arch>` is the machine architecture symbolic name, maybe `x86_64`, check in the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2014` to see what it is) ***precedes*** `/usr/bin`.

What method to use depends on personal preferences. On the Debian (virtual) machine I use for testing I write a file `texlive.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` containing the line

```
export PATH=/opt/texbin:${PATH}
```

(one can also set other variables such as `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH`) after having created the symbolic link

```
/opt/texbin -> /usr/local/texlive/2014/<arch>
```

In this way when a new distribution is released, I only need to recreate the symbolic link pointing to the new release. Others may prefer to modify the `/etc/environment` file, others may want to act on a user's basis, so changing `PATH` in `~/.profile`. Take your pick.